# Resize large portion of images (php or any other language)

Tags: php

We recently decided to redesign our old app which used 150x150 thumbnails. New thumbs are of size 250x250. Now i have to change all thumbs that were created by previous entries.

The function used for creating new thumbnails is php's `imagecopyresampled`.

Do you suggest resizing all the old thumbnails using php or any other more native os language / software that would resize them faster locally? (Software has to support `copyresampled` function or something with similar result).

Also, the job itself is a little complicated since there are some folders that has to be excluded when iterating trough the files.

```
level 1: company folder
level 2: company property folder, company products folder
level 3: there are images that have to be resized inside company property folder.

company 1
company 2
company 3
----company 3 property
--------image1.jpg (original size)
--------image1_thumb.jpg (old 150 thumb)
--------image2.jpg
--------image2_thumb.jpg
----company 3 products (folder also includes images but they should not be resized)
```

I could also use the other way and look for image names/paths in property `database`, but that would probably be slower than just iterating trough folders. What do you think?

Comment: Are you doing this as a one-off process, or will the resizing be a feature of your site?

Comment: It is a one-off process for replacing old thumbnails that are still of size 150x150px (thumbs that were created before the redesign).

Comment: I can't think of any batch software from the top of my head, but I can definetely tell you there's better solutions locally than running it through PHP

Comment: I can't recall either :) but there are lots of such apps, which vary in cost and effectiveness. I suspect that going from 150x to 250x is going to degrade a lot.

Comment: @AndyG no, i would not resize from 150 to 250. As you can see in my question there are also original sized images inside the folder. I just need to delete old thumbs and create new, 250 ones from big original.

Comment: if it's a one-off use something like http://imageresizer.codeplex.com/ and upload the resized  images.

Comment: @Webinan does it support iteration through specific folders, or do i have to do it manually for every image? It is kinda impossible since there are few hundred folders.

Comment: You may have more luck asking at http://superuser.com. Photoshop can be automated to do that, OS X Automator does it easily... depends what you have on your system.

Comment: @BikerJohn I don't have it installed anymore, you should try and check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like one time job? if so you use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)'s [`convert`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) utility to resize all thumb images at one hit:

```
$ convert -resize '250x250' image1.jpg image1_thumb.jpg
```

You can loop throght the images using proper pattern:

```
$ for i in $(find . -regex '.*image[0-9]+\.jpg'); do echo $i ; done
./image2.jpg
./image1.jpg
./image4.jpg
./image3.jpg
$
```

and convert them using the previous command:

```
for i in $(find . -regex '.*image[0-9]+\.jpg'); do
     convert -resize '250x250' $i $(echo $i | sed 's/.jpg/_thumb.jpg/g');
done
```

preview:

```
$ ls
image1.jpg  image2.jpg  image3.jpg  image4.jpg
$ for i in $(find . -regex '.*image[0-9]+\.jpg'); do echo $i ; done
./image2.jpg
./image1.jpg
./image4.jpg
./image3.jpg
$ for i in $(find . -regex '.*image[0-9]+\.jpg'); do
>      convert -resize '250x250' $i $(echo $i | sed 's/.jpg/_thumb.jpg/g');
> done
$ ls
image1.jpg  image1_thumb.jpg  image2.jpg  image2_thumb.jpg  image3.jpg  image3_thumb.jpg  image4.jpg  image4_thumb.jpg
$
```

let it runs until all images are converted.

Comment: i would not resize from 150 to 250 since it would affect quality. As you can see in my question there are also original sized images inside the folder. I just need to delete old thumbs and/or replace them with new, 250 ones created from big original.

Comment: @BikerJohn It's OK, you just need to change the command and select the original image as input and overwrite the thumb image by the new one.